How to convert Map.adjust to monadic?
In the code it works well as below
divide :: Int -> Int -> Either String Int
divide a 0 = Left "Error with 0"
divide a b = Right (a `div` b)

The code to be changed
Map.adjust (divide 3) "A" $ Map.fromList [("A",3),("B",0)]

The expected result should be :
Map.adjust (divide 3) "A" $ Map.fromList [("A",3),("B",0)] 
=>  Right $ Map.fromList [("A",1),("B",0)]   

Map.adjust (divide 3) "B" $ Map.fromList [("A",3),("B",0)]
=>  Left "Error with 0"

Or in general how to build a function like:
Map.adjust:: (a -> m a) -> k -> (Map k a) -> m (Map k a)

Thank you very much !

So for any Monad m, or is Either/Maybe sufficient?

The proposed type signature adjust:: (a -> m b) -> k -> (Map k a) -> m (Map k b) seems suspect, because it can change the type of the whole map even if the functions only modifies a single value inside it.

@willeM_VanOnsem I'm working with Either.. But it would be great to have more generic solution.

@danidiaz: yes, I assume it is a -> m a.

A function adjustM with type (a -> m a) -> k -> (Map k a) -> m (Map k a) can be defined on top of the already existing function alterF :: (Functor f, Ord k) => (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)) -> k -> Map k a -> f (Map k a).
alterF is more general because, besides allowing for effects, it also lets you remove the targeted value, or insert it when the key doesn't already exist. (That's what those Maybes are for in its signature).
adjustM :: (Ord k, Applicative m) => (a -> m a) -> k -> Map k a -> m (Map k a)
adjustM f = Map.alterF (\ma -> case ma of
   -- No value? We do nothing.
   Nothing -> pure Nothing
   -- There's a value? We transform it.
   Just v -> Just <$> f v)

Or, more succinctly,
adjustM :: (Ord k, Applicative m) => (a -> m a) -> k -> Map k a -> m (Map k a)
adjustM f = Map.alterF (traverse f)


(Or more succinctly still, adjustM = Map.alterF . traverse)

We can implement this by using insert instead:
updateM :: (Ord k, Applicative m) => (a -> m a) -> k -> Map k a -> m (Map k a)
updateM f k map = case (map !? k) of
  Just v -> flip (insert k) map <$> f v
  _ -> pure map
We thus first check if the key exists, if so run f v and then use that to insert the new value in the map.
This generates the expected result:
ghci> updateM (divide 3) "A" $ Data.Map.fromList [("A",3),("B",0)]
Right (fromList [("A",1),("B",0)])
ghci> updateM (divide 3) "B" $ Data.Map.fromList [("A",3),("B",0)]
Left "Error with 0"

